# Solving a sparse linear system using Strumpack in Fortran

Tags: fortran, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have to solve a sparse linear system in CSR format. My code uses the library Strumpack.
I can't figure out why it doesn't return the solution. The matrix in CSR format is constituted of col_index, row_index, and valeurs (real values stored in the matrix). The code reads the parameters from a file, assembles the matrix, then enters in in a "do while" loop.

```
program main
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
use strumpack
use hermite
use linalg
implicit none




integer(c_int) :: ierr
integer(c_int) :: k      ! grid dimension
integer, target :: matrice_dimension

integer  ::   Nx, i, troncature , nbblocs,j, Nv,r
real(rp) ::   Tfin ,dx,dxdemi,dt,date, tzero, tauzero, eps, dv,xj,vr , delta

integer, dimension(:), allocatable, target ::  row_index, col_index
integer  :: rc  
real(rp), dimension(:), allocatable, target :: D, Dnew, psi_v , diag , valeurs
real(rp), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: Mat  , D_matrice , solution_finale


! sparse solver object
type(STRUMPACK_SparseSolver) :: S



!!! lecture des parametres
open(unit = 10, file = "parametres.txt")
read(10,*)  Nx, Nv
read(10,'(E15.8)')  Tfin
read(10,*)  troncature
read(10,'(E15.8)') tzero
read(10,'(E15.8)') delta
read(10,'(E15.8)') eps
read(10,'(E15.8)') tauzero



!!!!! il y a nbblocs*nbblocs dans la matrice 
nbblocs = troncature + 1


matrice_dimension = (troncature+1)*Nx

!!!!! allocation 
!allocate(Mat((troncature+1)*Nx,(troncature+1)*Nx))
!allocate(diag(Nx*nbblocs))

allocate(D_matrice(Nx,nbblocs))
allocate(psi_v(0:troncature))
allocate(D(matrice_dimension))
allocate(Dnew(matrice_dimension))
allocate(solution_finale(Nx,Nv))



allocate(valeurs(8*Nx+7*(troncature-1)*Nx))
allocate(col_index(8*Nx+7*(troncature-1)*Nx))
allocate(row_index((troncature+1)*Nx+1))


!!!! pas de temps et d'espace et de vitesse
dx = (xdroite-xgauche)/real(Nx,rp)
dv = (vdroite-vgauche)/real(Nv-1,rp)


dt = 0.001_rp 


print*,""
print*," !!!!!!!!!!!! PARAMETRES  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
print*,"Tfin = ",Tfin
print*,"Intervalle [",xgauche,",",xdroite,"]"
print*,"dx =",dx,",dt =",dt
print*,"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
print*," " 





!!!!!! initialisation 

!!!!! D(t=0,x)
!call vect_init_cas1(nbblocs,Nx,dx,delta,c0,tzero,D)


!call vect_init(nbblocs,troncature,Nx,xgauche,dx,tzero,c0,D)
!print*,D

!call vect_init_trapeze(nbblocs,troncature,Nx,xgauche,dx,tzero,c0,D)



D = 1.0_rp
Dnew=5.0_rp



print*,D

call matricecreuse(dx,dt,tauzero,eps,tzero,Nx,troncature,valeurs,col_index,row_index)

!call STRUMPACK_init_mt(S, STRUMPACK_DOUBLE, STRUMPACK_MT, 0, c_null_ptr, 1)

call STRUMPACK_set_csr_matrix(S, c_loc(matrice_dimension), c_loc(row_index), c_loc(col_index), c_loc(valeurs), 0);

date = 0.0_rp


open(unit=50,file="erreur1.dat")
open(unit=51,file="erreur2.dat")

write(50,"(E15.8,x,E15.8)") date , sqrt(dx/(xdroite-xgauche)) * norm2(D(Nx+1:))
write(51,"(E15.8,x,E15.8)") date , erreur2(troncature,Nx,dx,tzero,D)



!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! RESOLUTION MATRICE PLEINE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

do while( date<Tfin) 
    dt = min(dt,Tfin-date)
    date = date  + dt
    print*,"date =",date
    ierr = STRUMPACK_solve(S, c_loc(D), c_loc(Dnew), 0);
    print*,"ierr=",ierr
    print*,Dnew
    D = Dnew
    write(50,"(E15.8,x,E15.8)") date , sqrt(dx/(xdroite-xgauche)) * norm2(D(Nx+1:))
    write(51,"(E15.8,x,E15.8)") date , erreur2(troncature,Nx,dx,tzero,D)
    exit
end do
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

close(50)
close(51)

!!!!!!!!! EVALUATION DE LA SOLUTION SUR UNE GRILLE xj, j=1,...,Nx et vr, r=1,...,Nv


D_matrice = reshape(D, (/Nx,nbblocs/))

do j=1,Nx
    xj = (xgauche+0.5_rp*dx) + real(j-1,rp)*dx
    D_matrice(j,:) = sqrt(rho_infini(tzero,c0,xj)) * D_matrice(j,:)
end do

do r=0,Nv-1
    vr = vgauche + r*dv
    call hermite_polynome(troncature,vr,psi_v)
    psi_v = maxwellien(tzero,vr)*psi_v
    solution_finale(:,r+1) = matmul(D_matrice,psi_v) 
end do


print*,"Minimum de la solution : ",minval(solution_finale)


!!!!!! ECRITURE DES FICHIERS 
open(unit=50,file="approximation.dat")
open(unit=51,file="stationnaire.dat")
open(unit=52,file="erreur.dat")
open(unit=53,file="initial.dat")

do r=1,Nv
    do j=1,Nx
        xj = (xgauche+0.5_rp*dx) + real(j-1,rp)*dx
        vr = vgauche + real(r-1,rp)*dv
        write(50,"(E15.8,x,E15.8,x,E15.8)") xj,vr,solution_finale(j,r)
        write(51,"(E15.8,x,E15.8,x,E15.8)") xj,vr, stationnaire(c0,tzero,xj,vr)
        write(52,"(E15.8,x,E15.8,x,E15.8)") xj,vr, abs(solution_finale(j,r)-stationnaire(c0,tzero,xj,vr))

    end do
    write(50,*) ""
    write(51,*) ""
    write(52,*) ""
end do


do r=1,Nv
    vr = vgauche + real(r-1,rp)*dv
    write(53,"(E15.8,x,E15.8,x,E15.8)") vr,solution_finale(1,r),f_init(c0,tzero,1.0_rp,vr)
end do

close(50)
close(51)
close(52)
close(53)

call execute_command_line ("gnuplot trace.p")





!!!!!!!! Désallocation mémoire, fin du code
deallocate(D_matrice,D,Dnew,psi_v)



end program main
```

I'm sure that the matrix is correct (I used Scipy on it and it works great). I've tried to debug it, by setting values in D and Dnew before the loop, and by printing the vector and ierr. After one iteration, Dnew is still 5, and ierr is 0. I think it means that Strumpack don't solve the system. Hence, it is likely that I missuses Strumpack before entering in the loop. I struggle to find an explanation on [the strumpack's website](https://portal.nersc.gov/project/sparse/strumpack/v5.0.0/index.html) .

Does anyone has any answer?

Best regards.

Comment: Welcome, plesse take the [tour]. I also suggest reading [ask] and [mcve]. What exactly happens when you run the code? What is the actual output and how does the input look like? Try to create a small reproducible example.